# Logging Events---Looking For a Good Way

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I created a program that monitors for events.
I want to log these events "in the right way".
Currently I have a string array, log[500][100].
Each line is a string of characters (up to 100) that report something about the event.
I have it set up so that only the last 500 events are saved in the array.
After that, new events overwrite the oldest events.

Currently I just keep revolving through the array until the program terminates, then I write the array to a file.

Going forward I would like to view the log in real time, any time I wish, without disturbing the event processing and logging process.

I considered opening the file for "appending" but here are my concerns:

(1) The program is running on a Raspberry Pi which has a flash memory as a "disk drive".  I believe flash memories have a limited number of write cycles before problems can occur.  This program runs 24/7 "forever" so I am afraid the "disk drive" will "wear out".

(2) I am using pretty much all the CPU capacity of the RPi so I don't want to add a lot of overhead/CPU cycles.

How would experienced programmers attack this problem?

Please go easy on me, this is my first C program.

[EDIT]
I began reviewing all the information and I became intrigued by Mark A's suggestion for tmpfs.  I looked into it more and I am sure this answers my question.  It allows the creation of files in RAM not the SD card.  They are lost on power down but I don't care.
In order to keep the files from growing to large I created a double buffer approach.  First I write 500 events to file A then switch to file B. When 500 events have been written to file B I close and reopen file A (to delete the contents and start at 0 events) and switch to writing to file A.  I found I needed to fflush(file...) after each write or else the file was empty until fclose.
Normally that would be OK but right now I am fighting a nasty segmentation fault so I want as much insight into what is going on.  When I hit the fault, I never get to my fclose statements.

Comment: [`syslog`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html)?

Comment: If you're that concerned about flash wear then you can log to a file in a [tmpfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html).  That opens up the possibility to use a regular logging library with rotating log files.

Comment: If you're running the Raspbian OS, it uses systemd, and so you can use sd_journal_print() to write to the system journal. It's designed for exactly that kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and to C programming!  A wonderful world of possibilities awaits you.

I have several thoughts in response to your situation.

**The very short summary is to use `stdout` and delegate the output-file management to the shell.**

The longer, rambling answer full of my personal musing is as follows:

**1 :**  A very typical thing for C programs to do is *not* be in charge of how outputs are kept.  You might have heard of the "built in" file handles, `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.  These file handles are (under normal circumstances) always available to your program for input (from `stdin`) and output (`stdout` and `stderr`).  As you might guess from their names `stdout` is customarily used for regular output and `stderr` is customarily used for error / exception output.  It is exceedingly typical for a C program to simply read from `stdin` and output to `stdout` and `stderr`, and let *something else* (e.g., the shell) take care of what those actually are.

For example, reading from `stdin` means that your program can be used for keyboard entry *and* for file reading, *without needing to change your program's code*.  The same goes for `stdout` and `stderr`; simply output to those file handles, and let the user decide whether those should go to the screen or be redirected to a file.  And, because `stdout` and `stderr` are separate file handles, the user can have them go to separate 'destinations'.

In your case, to implement this, drop the array entirely, and simply

```
fprintf(stdout, "event notice : %s\n", eventdetailstring);
```

(or similar) every time your program has something to say.  Take a look at `fflush()`, too, because of potential output buffering.

**2a :** This gets you continuous output.  This itself can help with your concern about memory wear on the Pi's flash disk.  If you do something like:

```
eventmonitor > logfile
```

then `logfile` will be being appended to during the lifetime of your program, which will tend to be writing to new parts of the flash disk.  Of course, if you only ever append, you will eventually run out of space on the disk, so you might set up a `cron` job to kill the currently running `eventmonitor` and restart it every day at midnight.  Done with the above command, that would cause it to overwrite `logfile` once per day.  This prevents endless growth, and it *might* even use a new physical area of the flash drive for the new file (even though it's the same name; underneath, it's a different file, with a different inode, etc.)  But even if it reuses the exact same area of the flash drive, now you are down to worrying if this will last more than 10,000 days, instead of 10,000 writes.  I'm betting that within 10,000 days, new options will be available -- worst case, you buy a new Pi every 27 years or so!

There are other possible variations on this theme, as well.  e.g., you could have a sophisticated script kicked off by `cron` every day at midnight that kills any currently running `eventmonitor`, deletes output files older than a week, and starts a new `eventmonitor` outputting to a file whose filename is based partly on the date so that past days' file aren't overwritten.  But all of this is in the realm of *using* your program.  You can make your program easier to use by *writing* it to use `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

**2b :**  Or, you can just have `stdout` go to the screen, which is typically how it already is when a program is started from an interactive shell / terminal window.  I imagine you could have the Pi running headless most of the time, and when you want to see what your program is outputting, hook up a monitor.  Generally, things will stay running between disconnecting and reconnecting your monitor.  This avoids affecting the flash drive at all.

**3 :**  Another approach is to have your event monitoring program send its output somewhere off-system.  This is getting into more advanced programming territory, so you might want to save this for a later enhancement, after you've mastered more of the basics.  But, your program could establish a network connection to, say, a JSON API and send event information there.  This would let you separate the functions of *event monitoring* from *event reporting*.

You will discover as you learn more programming that this idea of *separation of concerns* is an important concept, and applies at various levels of a program or a system of interoperating programs.  In this case, the Pi is a good fit for the data monitoring aspect because it is a lightweight solution, and some other system with more capacity and more stable storage can cover the data collection aspect.

Comment: *In your case, to implement this, drop the array entirely, and simply `fprintf(stdout, "event notice : %s\n", eventdetailstring);`*  No, just no.  Using `stdout` (or `stderr`) for logging is never a good practice.  Especially for "This program runs 24/7 *"forever"*".  Using `stdout`/`stderr` irrevocably ties the process to one log file and makes log file rotation impossible, among many other problems.  `eventmonitor > logfile`?!?!  You really need to think about what happens in that case should `logfile` fill up the filesystem...

Comment: @AndrewHenle : I guess you didn't read the rest of my answer, where I addressed exactly the points you raised ...

Comment: Wow, you folks have provided some good possibilities.  Being a novice I have do some research to know what they mean.  This could take some time.  Also, I got some message about a "Suggested Edit" that removed my two paragraphs starting with "(1)" and "(2)".  They still seem to be there so, am I the only one to see them or can everyone see them?

Comment: @PeteC : at this particular moment, I see the "(1)" and "(2)" paragraphs; I'm guessing that if you accept the suggested edit, they will be removed, and that if you decline the suggested edit, they will remain; but I'm doing some guesswork there, since I cannot see exactly what you see

Comment: Well, to add to the confusion, I went to the page that suggested removing (1) and (2) and clicked "reject".  i got a message saying "the owner has already approved the edit".  I don't think I ever did.  Anyway I clicked "reject". Now (1) is missing but not (2).  Oh well??????